# Hibernate calling a stored procedure with named queries

Tags: java, hibernate

I am still learning about hibernate. I am wondering if it is possible to use a named query to call a stored procedure with output and input parameters?

Is this a good idea in terms of security, is practical, good practice etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

A) [How to Call Stored Procedure In Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/)

B) [call-stored-procedure-in-hiber](http://www.javaquery.com/2014/01/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in.html)

Trusted Links Only